# <select> values doubled when sent with $_POST

Tags: php, select, post

I have this `<select>` in a `form`:

```
<select name='list1[]' multiple>
<option value='1' class='name'>Way 1</option>
<option disabled>||| Some information</option>
<option value='2' class='name'>Way 2</option>
<option disabled>||| Some information</option>
</select>
```

Then I select both options (with value 1 and value 2) and sent it with `$_POST`.

But when I print `$_POST` I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 )
```

The option with value 2 is doubled. I don't know why.

When I only select the option with value 2(or only value 1), I get the right output:

```
 Array ( [0] => 2 )
```

What can I do?

Comment: Got something here - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=17739

Comment: <select name='list1' multiple>

Comment: @Parag Tyagi: Hm, that would be a shame. But it's the first time, this happens for me. And it happens with all of the major browsers.

@ alexey palamar: I need an array, so I have to put the [] in it